# Kendo MVC Dropdownlist ValueTemplate() cause dataSource.read() fail

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a kendo MVC dropdownlist as follow:

```html
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(model => model.Storeroom)
  .Template("#=StoreroomCode# - #=Description#")
  .ValueTemplate("#=StoreroomCode# - #=Description#")
  .DataTextField("StoreroomCode")
  .DataValueField("StoreroomID")
  .DataSource(d =>
  {
    d.Read(read =>
  {
    read.Action("GetStoreRoomDropDownRepository", "Material")).Type(HttpVerbs.Post);
    });
  })
  .OptionLabel("--- Please Select ---")
)
```

And I have a javascript function which manually refresh it when I click a button

```js
    function BindStoreRoomDropDown(ItemID) {
        var ddl = $('#Storeroom').data("kendoDropDownList");
        ddl.dataSource.read({ itemID: ItemID });
    }
```

The problem is, when this JS function is called, the dropdownlist did not refresh, it did not even post to corresponding server side action. I thought it may be some JS error before post action, but no, there is no any JS errors.

More interesting is that, when I remove `.ValueTemplate()`, everything goes right! The action is called and the correct list is returned!

What is the possible cause of this behavior and how can I fix it? Thanks!

**EDITED**

```js
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetStoreRoomDropDownRepository(int? itemID, string whereclause){
  if(!itemID.HasValue) return Json("");
  var CostCenterList = SiteCostCenterService.Instance.getCodeCenterParaBySiteCode(woContext, whereclause);
  var storeRoomQuery = StoreroomService.Instance.getStoreroomListByItemID(pmsContext, itemID.Value, CostCenterList);
    return Json(storeRoomQuery.Distinct().ToList());
}
```

Comment: Did you make sure ItemID is not null? Is there a default value you can set using the .Value() property? Also, you are calling that datasource read without sending in an ItemID and then rebinding with an ItemID. Is that an optional field?

Comment: @Irb I checked the network traffic, there is not even one request to the action, I think it is not related to ItemID is null or not?

Comment: Could you please provide code of method "GetStoreRoomDropDownRepository()"?

Comment: I have tried to reproduce issue but to no avail, by using your code. It works perfectly.

Comment: @JayeshGoyani There is no js error, also no post request to the controller, I suppose the bug is not at server side, still I am facing this problem till now